# Default Android Gallery App doesn't compile :(

Tags: android, system, gallery, default, android-source

I'm trying to make a mobile mashup of existing apps

Got Default Android System Camera App for 2.2 Froyo from
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/froyo-release
Works and compiles great

Got Default Android System Gallery App for 2.2 Froyo from
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/froyo-release

Doesn't compile! Some errors -

> local variables mLength, mHeight ... cannot be resolved
>
> import android.provider.DrmStore;... cannot be resolved

How can I compile and run the default gallery app on Froyo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I compile and run the default gallery app on Froyo?

By grabbing the entire firmware and compiling the entire firmware. Most of the AOSP apps are not designed to be built standalone against the Android SDK.